# Google Sheets averageif with multiple criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, average

Looking for a formula that averages the numbers located in the 'Salary' column as long as any of the priority columns in a row contain both 'Car' and 'House' in any order, so that this.

| Name | Priority | Priority | Priority | Salary | Average Salary of Car/Home owners |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | House | Car | Loans | 40,000 |  |
| Ned | House | Groceries | Car | 120,000 |  |
| Dom | Family | Car | Going Fast | 450,000 |  |
| Thanos | Stones | Balance | House | 9,000,000 |  |
| Homer | Donuts | Car | House | 20,000 |  |

could become

| Name | Priority | Priority | Priority | Salary | Average Salary of Car/Home owners |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | House | Car | Loans | 40,000 | 60,000 |
| Ned | House | Groceries | Car | 120,000 |  |
| Dom | Family | Car | Going Fast | 450,000 |  |
| Thanos | Stones | Balance | House | 9,000,000 |  |
| Homer | Donuts | Car | House | 20,000 |  |

The average salary column would be used just for the formula in row 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option could be:

```
=ArrayFormula(AVERAGEIF(MMULT((B2:D="house")+(B2:D="car"),ROW(A1:A3)^0),2,E2:E))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @basic, regarding how this works what is the Row(A1:A3)^0 telling the formula to do?

Comment: @LoganSchenkey this is second argument for ```MMULT``` and returns array of ones. Row count in It corresponds to column count in first argument. You can use any other function that can return array like ```SEQUENCE``` or even ```{1;1;1}```. Look at [MMULT explanation](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/mmult-function-in-google-sheets/),

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can think of is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(REGEXMATCH(B2:B&C2:C&D2:D,"House|Car"),E2:E)
```